# Detect which UITableViewCell is tapped, and change a UILabel value?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I was wondering how one might go about making it so when you tap on a `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView`, a method is called to change the text of a `UILabel`. Much appreciated!

Comment: While the answer was provided, you should seriously look into the Apple docs. Hover your mouse over any object in your source (TableView variable, NSString property, etc) and Option+Left Click to see documentation on it. It will provide you with every property and method for that object and a detailed explanation on what it does and how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have not tried using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, You could do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    self.label.text = @"Test";

}
```